# Calling this.scene.restart() in Phaser 3 TypeError: this.body is undefined

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm trying to restart the game scene in Phaser 3, and when calling this.scene.restart I get an error saying "this.body is undefined" at setVelocityX in the phaser.js script (line 169442 in the unminified script if that helps)

I am using the latest version of Phaser, v3.19.0.
The hitEnemy function is called when the player sprite collides with the enemy, which pauses the physics and sets gameOver to true. In the update() function I'm checking if gameOver is true, as well as if the "R" key is pressed, in which case scene.restart() is called
Below is part of my code:

```
var config = {
    scene: 'scene1',
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    scene: 'scene1',
    width: 1080,
    height: 890,
    pixelArt: true,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            gravity: {
                y: 500
            },
            debug: true
        }
    },
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: updateDirect
    }
    };
   function preload() {
        var progressBar = this.add.graphics();
        var progressBox = this.add.graphics();
        progressBox.fillStyle(0x222222, 0.8);
        progressBox.fillRect(380, 270, 320, 50);

        var width = this.cameras.main.width;
        var height = this.cameras.main.height;
        var loadingText = this.make.text({
            x: width / 2,
            y: height / 2 - 50,
            text: 'Loading...',
            style: {
                font: '20px monospace',
                fill: '#ffffff'
            }
        });
        loadingText.setOrigin(0.5, 0.5);

        var percentText = this.make.text({
        x: width / 2,
        y: height / 2 - 5,
        text: '0%',
        style: {
            font: '18px monospace',
            fill: '#ffffff'
            }
        });
        percentText.setOrigin(0.5, 0.5);

        var assetText = this.make.text({
            x: width / 2,
            y: height / 2 + 50,
            text: '',
            style: {
                font: '18px monospace',
                fill: '#ffffff'
            }
        });
        assetText.setOrigin(0.5, 0.5);

        this.load.image('bgtile', 'bgtile.jpg');
        this.load.image('background', 'assets/lava/background2.png');
        this.load.image('platformdefault', 'assets/lava/lavaplatform.png');
        this.load.image('platform400', 'assets/lava/platform4002.png');
        this.load.image('platform500', 'assets/lava/platform500.png');
        this.load.image('platform300', 'assets/lava/platform300.png');
        this.load.image('platform200', 'assets/lava/platform200.png');
        this.load.image('platform100', 'assets/lava/platform100.png');

        this.load.image('stopper', 'assets/lava/stopper.png');
        this.load.image('sign', 'assets/lava/sign2.png');

        this.load.image('enemy', 'assets/lava/enemy2.png');
        this.load.spritesheet('dude', 'assets/sprites/dude.png', {
            frameWidth: 32,
            frameHeight: 48
        });

        this.load.spritesheet('lavafloor', 'assets/lava/lavasprite.png', {
            frameWidth: 320,
            frameHeight: 100
        });
        //scary flash ooo
        flash = this.load.image('flash', 'assets/images/blue-flash.png');
        this.load.image('floor', 'assets/lava/floor.png');

        //audio
        this.load.audio('fantastic', 'assets/audio/fantastic.mp3');
        this.load.audio('wait', 'assets/audio/wait.mp3');
        this.load.audio('ward', 'assets/audio/ward.mp3');
        this.load.audio('whisper1', 'assets/audio/whisper1.mp3');
        this.load.audio('whisper2', 'assets/audio/whisper2.mp3');
        this.load.audio('whisper3', 'assets/audio/whisper3.mp3');
        this.load.audio('whisper4', 'assets/audio/whisper4.mp3');
        this.load.audio('hey', 'assets/audio/hey.mp3');

    //  this.load.video('spider', 'assets/video/spider.mp4');
    //  this.load.video('skull', 'assets/video/skull.mp4');

        this.load.on('progress', function (value) {
            progressBar.clear();
            progressBar.fillStyle(0xffffff, 1);
            progressBar.fillRect(390, 280, 300 * value, 30);
            percentText.setText(parseInt(value * 100) + '%');
        });

        this.load.on('fileprogress', function (file) {
        //  console.log(file.src);
            assetText.setText('Loading asset: ' + file.key);
        });

        this.load.on('complete', function () {
            progressBar.destroy();
            progressBox.destroy();          
            loadingText.destroy();
            percentText.destroy();
            assetText.destroy();
        });
    }


    function create() {
        bgtile = this.add.image(400, 300, 'background');
        this.cameras.main.setBounds(0, 0, 10392, 100);
        this.physics.world.setBounds(0, 0, 10392, 710);

        cameraHeight = this.cameras.height;
        cameraWidth = this.cameras.width;
        platforms = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
        stoppers = this.physics.add.staticGroup();

        var floor = platforms.create(400, 775, 'floor');

        sign = this.add.image(400, 560, 'sign').setScale(0.06);

        platform1 = createPlatform400(400, 600);
        platform2 = createPlatform100(1100, 200);
        platform3 = createPlatform300(700,500);
        platform4 = createPlatform200(900, 350);
        platform5 = createPlatform200(1325, 317);
        platform6 = createPlatform100(1605, 358);

        fantastic = this.sound.add('fantastic', { loop: false, volume: 0.2 });
        wait = this.sound.add('wait', { loop: true, volume: 0.3 });
        ward = this.sound.add('ward', { loop: true, volume: 0.2 });
        whisper1 = this.sound.add('whisper1', { loop: false, volume: 0.1 });
        whisper2 = this.sound.add('whisper2', { loop: false, volume: 0.2 });
        whisper3 = this.sound.add('whisper3', { loop: false, volume: 0.2 });
        whisper4 = this.sound.add('whisper4', { loop: false, volume: 0.2 });
        hey = this.sound.add('hey', {loop: true, volume: 0.2})

        whisper2.play();
        whisper2.on('complete', function(){
            fantastic.play();
        });
        fantastic.on('complete', function(){
            hey.play();
        });

        var frameNames = this.anims.generateFrameNames('lavafloor', {
                     start: 1, end: 4
        });

        this.anims.create({ key: 'lavaAnim', frames: frameNames, frameRate: 4, repeat: -1 });

        //player anims
        this.anims.create({
            key: 'left',
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('dude', {
                start: 0,
                end: 3
            }),
            //frames refer to spritesheet frames, between 0 and 3 it will be left facing
            frameRate: 10, //10 fps
            repeat: -1 //stop animation
        });
        this.anims.create({
            key: 'turn',
            frames: [{
                key: 'dude',
                frame: 4
            }],
            frameRate: 20
        });
        this.anims.create({
            key: 'right',
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('dude', {
                start: 5,
                end: 8
            }),
            frameRate: 10,
            repeat: -1
        });

        physics = this.physics; //get the reference to physics to create lava and enemies or platforms

        dude = this.physics.add.sprite(0, 100, 'dude').setScale(1.5);
        createLava(1274, 760);//add 320 to x for continuous lava
        createLava(2000, 760); 


        enemies = this.physics.add.group();
        spawnEnemy(platform3);
        wasd = this.input.keyboard.addKeys({
            up: Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.W,
            down: Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.S,
            left: Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.A,
            right: Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.D,
            space: Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.SPACE,
            restart: Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.R,
            pause: Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.P,
            action: Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.F
        });

        dude.body.setGravityY(800);
        dude.setCollideWorldBounds(true); //prevent running outside game window

        this.cameras.main.startFollow(dude, true, 0.08, 0.08);
        this.cameras.main.setZoom(1);
        this.physics.add.collider(dude, platforms);

        this.physics.add.collider(enemies, stoppers, hitStopper, null, this);
        this.physics.add.overlap(dude, sign, showText, null, this);

        this.physics.add.collider(enemies, platforms);
        this.physics.add.collider(dude, enemies, hitEnemy, null, this);

        onScreenText = this.add.text(16, 16, '', {
            fontSize: '32px',
            fill: '#fff'
        });
        playerPosText = this.add.text(dude.x+300, 16, '', {
            fontSize: '32px',
            fill: '#fff'
        });

        playerPosText.setScrollFactor(0);
    }
    function hitEnemy(dude, enemies) {
        this.physics.pause();
        dude.setTint(0xff0000);
        dude.anims.play('turn');
        gameOver = true;

    }

    function updateDirect() {
        playerPosText.setText('X: ' + parseInt(dude.x) + ' ' + 'Y: ' + parseInt(dude.y));
        if ((dude.x >= 380 && dude.x <= 430) && dude.y == 544) {
            showText("test");
        } else {
            showText('');
        }

        if(gameOver){
            showText("You died\nPress R to restart");
            if(wasd.restart.isDown){
                this.scene.restart();
                gameOver = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have used this in a project mostly based on the tutorial example, where it worked fine, and I'm using the same code here. I am very new to Phaser and game development in general, so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Could you add your `create()` and `preload()` methods to the code you provided please?

Comment: Added the create and preload functions to the code provided. I've tried calling scene.restart() a bunch more times and now I'm getting a different error, "this.frame.source is null". I worked around that by destroying the game completely, removing the canvas and creating a new game, but that is less than ideal

Answer (score 0):

You coud do something like this :

```
create(){
    duce.isReady = false
    // Your code here...
    dude.isReady = true
}

update(){
    if(dude.isReady){
        dude.body.setVelocityX(...)
        // Rest of your code concerning dude
    }
}
```